# Short story about a man who has mind transferred into a woman's body

Tags: story-identification, mind-uploading

It was a part of short story about a man who wakes up in a woman's body. I read it some time in the eighties. There was a black and white illustration of the "woman" looking into a mirror, and  there was a human-like dog attendant. I seem to remember the population was kept in stasis and only a few were allowed to be out at any given time.

Comment: Why the "mind-uploading" tag? I don't see anything about a computer or computational device in your description. If a computer is part of the story, please edit that into your question.

Comment: I think part of the story had something about downloading it into the body available.